# Warning: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Tags: java

Sometimes I see this warning when I click in Eclipse to compile my Java program:

> java version "1.8.0_241"Java(TM)
> SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM)  64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

What does it mean? Should I update something? It seems that they are both version 1.8.

I can compile my program if I restart Eclipse, but I really want to know how I can fix this.

Comment: That is **not** a warning, that **is** your JRE version. An informational message. Not sure why you're getting it (only sometimes).

Comment: You'd see the same output if you were to run `java -version`. I have no idea why that would happen while you're trying to compile. Does the "Build Project" action complete or hang? Any error?

Comment: thank you for your answers and sorry for my late reply! This issue disappeared soon, I think what I did is to upgrade the Eclipse version. (Or maybe Java version, can't remember exactly though). Anyway, thx!